# run vscode chrome debugger with its extensions

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code

Is there any way we can launch the chrome window with all the extensions installed on chrome?

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://site.example.com/",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 55):

Setting the `userDataDir` property in the launch config to `false` will allow you to launch Chrome using your personal user profile. However, I would suggest keeping your debugging environment sandboxed and separated from your personal profile instead.

By default, Chrome debugger will create a new profile for your debugging session and will persist until you restart your computer. The profile directory will be in your `%TEMP%` folder. The trick here is to create a profile just for your workspace. You could then configure this profile to have whatever extensions and other settings that you need. We just need to make it persist permanently by specifying a different location.

Instead, set the `userDataDir` property to a path in your `.vscode` directory (and ignore in your source control). It will create the profile in that directory you set. I use:

```
${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/vscode-chrome-debug-userdatadir
```

Then when you run the debugger, it will create a profile in that directory that should persist indefinitely. You could then install all the extensions you want, all without muddying up your personal profile.

If you want a central debugging workspace to be used for multiple projects, you could put it in your home folder (or other location) rather than your project workspace.

```
${env:HOME}/.vscode/vscode-chrome-debug-userdatadir
```

Comment: Profile directory must pass as runTimeArgs.

"runtimeArgs": ["--profile-directory=${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/vscode-chrome-debug-userdatadir"]

Comment: Launching chrome in debug mode only works when the userDataDir is not already in use by another currently running session. This is why in other configurations you are required to close all instances.

Comment: If chrome is running on Windows (even if node is running in wsl), on can use "--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\DebugVSCode".
DebugVsCode is just an arbitrary name to avoid collision with the regular directory

Answer (score 13):

One way is to prevent the debugger from starting a chrome instance with a seperate profile.

Just add `"userDataDir": false` within `"configurations"` to your `launch.json`.
Close all Chrome instances, than start debugging from Visual Studio Code.

Your previous chrome session should open including a new Tab serving your files.

Afterwards you can start/stop debugging without closing and reopening chrome.

*Source: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome*