# How to run chrome in debug mode with current user profile?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I can do this, if no chrome running on my machine. But if one instance is already running, this command just open a new window without debugging.

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222`

And in this case I can start chrome only if specify `--user-data-dir`.

I tried

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check  --user-data-dir=/Users/nazarkalituk/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default`

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially want to set your userDataDir to false in your launch.json. Here is an image of how it would look.

[How to set the UserDataDir to false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkAYb.png)

It will take you the current profile you are currently in.

If it fails to connect to the current profile, or if you want a better option entirely, I recommend going to these links for more info:

https://briandesousa1.wordpress.com/2018/05/12/using-a-chrome-developer-profile-with-visual-studio-code-debugger/

[run vscode chrome debugger with its extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51725854/run-vscode-chrome-debugger-with-its-extensions)